# Before and after while for

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Hello,**

I would like put "append" before my while (for) and put after "append_after"

```
 ****
 append = '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12" ><div class="carousel slide media-carousel" data-interval="false" id="media"><div class="carousel-inner" ><div class="item active"><div class="row">';

var newHTML = [];
var counter = 16;

for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

output = '';

 if (i % counter === 0) {
    output += '</div>';
    output += '</div>';
    output += '<div class="item">';
    output += '<div class="row">';      
}
output += '<div class="col-md-2">';
output += '<img src="' + results[i].Name + '.png" />';
output += '</div>';

newHTML.push(output);
}   
 $("#update").html(newHTML);

 append_after = '</div></div></div></div></div></div></div>';
 ****
```

Do you know how i can do that ?

ps : my code its not full.

Thx

Comment: you have done so - please clarify the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `push` it to the `newHTML` array, same way you do with your `output` variable:

```
append = '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12" ><div class="carousel slide media-carousel" data-interval="false" id="media"><div class="carousel-inner" ><div class="item active"><div class="row">';

var newHTML = [];
var counter = 16;

newHTML.push(append)

for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
   ...
   ...
}   

append_after = '</div></div></div></div></div></div></div>';

newHTML.push(append_after)
```